# r keeping 0.0 when using paste or paste0

Tags: r, paste, digits, significant-digits

This is a simple question but it is starting to annoy me that I cant find a solution....

I would like to be able to keep the 0.0 when using it as an output when using paste or paste0 so if i have the following:

```
y <- c(-1.5,-1.0,-0.5,0.0,0.5,1.0,1.5)
> y
[1] -1.5 -1.0 -0.5  0.0  0.5  1.0  1.5
paste0("x",y,"x")
```

I get:

```
[1] "x-1.5x" "x-1x"   "x-0.5x" "x0x"    "x0.5x"  "x1x"    "x1.5x"
```

but want:

```
[1] "x-1.5x" "x-1.0x"   "x-0.5x" "x0.0x"    "x0.5x"  "x1.0x"    "x1.5x"
```

Comment: Do you want only `0.0` not `1.0`  and `-1.0`

Comment: @mnel, good question. I didn't notice that in the output.

Comment: apologies I wanted 1.0 and -1.0 as well... but the below answers have solved my problem so thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use `sprintf()`:

```
paste0("x", sprintf("%.1f", y), "x")
```

Answer (score 11):

There's also `formatC`:

```
paste0("x", formatC(y, digits = 1, format = "f"), "x")
```

Answer (score 9):

There is also `format` and `drop0trailing`

```
paste0('x',format(y,drop0Trailing = F),'x')
```

And, if you really want only `0` replaced with `0.0`, not (`1.0` or `-1.0`)
then

```
paste0('x',gsub(x = gsub(x = format(y, drop0trailing = T),'0$', '0.0'),' ',''),'x')
## [1] "x-1.5x" "x-1x"   "x-0.5x" "x0.0x"  "x0.5x"  "x1x"    "x1.5x"
```

Or, as @mrdwab suggested (and is less typying)

```
paste0('x',gsub("^0$", "0.0", as.character(y)),'x')
```

Comment: My `gsub` was a little different: `gsub("^0$", "0.0", as.character(y))`.

Comment: Much cleaner! - added to my answer